# How to create json array with the inner array in javascript and access it

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to create an object with an array property which looks like this:

```
var arrayOfUsers = {
  id: "some user id",
  username : "some names",
  roles : [array with roles]
}
```

And i would like to access an element by `id`, something like, `arrayOfUsers['some id']['roles'];` 
I am new to json. I've tried different ways, but always ended up with bunch of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is a JavaScript object. JSON is a string representation of JavaScript objects.

Second, it's important to know the difference between an object and an array. In general, consider Objects to be defined with curly braces `{ }` and Arrays with  braces `[ ]`

Values in Arrays are accessed by their index with the `arr[index]` syntax while objects use `obj[key]` syntax to access the value assigned to some key on the object.

For your scenario, I'd avoid using arrays, because you want to be able to access objects by key, not by index.

```
var users = {
    "some user id": {
        username : "some names",
        roles : {
            "some role id": {
                name: "role name"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

In reality, this isn't a very effective data structure, because you'd likely want to deal with arrays for looping, rendering, etc, but to answer your question about being able to index by the Id of user and role, this is how your data would have to be structured.

Comment: so, there is no way to make index a key to array? better to go for javascript object?

Comment: Yes, if you want to be able to access a value by id, you'll have to use an object, not an array.

Comment: I think I will be going for the objects then, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you declare:

```
 var currentUser,
     currentRole,
     arrayOfUsers = {
         id: 1,
         username: "Sample Value",
         roles: [{
             roleId: 1,
             name: "Admin"
         },
         {
             roleId: 2,
             name: "Cashier"
         }]
     };
```

This is how you access it:

```
 for (var i = arrayOfUsers.length; i--;) {
     currentUser = arrayOfUsers[i];

     for (var x = currentUser.roles.length; x--;) {
         currentRole = currentUser.roles[x];
         console.log("ID=" + currentRole.id + "Name=" + currentRole.name);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to make difference between **array** which defined by `[]`, and Objects, by `{}`.

If you want to make an array of JSON, you can do the following :

```
var arrayRoles = [{
  idRole: 1,
  type: 'admin'
}, {
  idRole: 2,
  type: 'user'
}];

var userArray = [{
  id: 1,
  username: 'toto',
  roles: arrayRoles
}, {
  id: 2,
  username: 'titi',
  roles: arrayRoles
}, {
  id: 3,
  username: 'toto',
  roles: arrayRoles
}];
```

Then, if you want to iterate over all your data, you can do it by using **forEach** loop, which tends to be more elegant :

```
userArray.forEach(function(elm){
  //Our roles array
  var roles = elm.roles;
  //For all item in roles array
  roles.forEach(function(value){
    //display type of role, for example.
    console.log(value.type);
  });
});
```

But if you want to **search** a specific item in your JSON array, you can use **filter** method, by using high order function.

```
function filterBy(key, filter){
  return function(elm){
    return elm[key] === filter;
  }
}
```

Then, you can apply this function to your **filter**, by passing specific field and value, and it will return an array of results :

```
var filtered = userArray.filter(filterBy('username', 'toto'));

//Display '1'
console.log(filtered[0].id);

//Display '3'
console.log(filtered[1].id);
```